# Create array of objects from an object using javascipt?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, lodash, javascript-objects

My initial data is coming like this..

```
let initial = {
  labels: ['label1', 'label2', 'label3'],
  children: ['child1', 'child2', 'child3'],
  numbers: [1 , 2 , 3]
};
```

I need output in this format..

```
FINAL_OUTPUT = [
  { labels: 'label1', children: 'child1', numbers: 1 },
  { labels: 'label2', children: 'child2', numbers: 2 },
  { labels: 'label3', children: 'child3', numbers: 3 }
];
```

Separated the keys and values from the initial object. But struck in creating array of objects from the same. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get the entries and map the inner array with the values at the given index.

```js
let initial = { labels: ['label1', 'label2', 'label3'], children: ['child1', 'child2', 'child3'], numbers: [1, 2, 3] },
    result = Object
        .entries(initial)
        .reduce((r, [k, a]) => a.map((v, i) => ({ ...(r[i] || {}), [k]: v })), []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you @Nina Scholz for the timely and perfect dynamic response I need.

Answer (score 0):

This should do exactly what you want, assuming all arrays have equal length. With a bit of creativity this algorithm can be generalized to objects of arbitrary fields count. Here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gyn9kmx6/).

```
let initial = {
   labels: [
      'label1', 
      'label2', 
      'label3'
   ],
   children: [
      'child1', 
      'child2', 
      'child3'
   ],
   numbers: [
      1, 
      2, 
      3
   ]
};

function convertObjectToArray(
   labels,
   children,
   numbers
) {
   let final = [];

   for (let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
      final.push({
         labels: labels[i],
         children: children[i],
         numbers: numbers[i],
      });
  }

  return final;
}

console.log(convertObjectToArray(
   initial.labels,
   initial.children,
   initial.numbers
));
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the prompt response @federico-dondi!! 
The 'initial data' can have 'n' number of objects (more than 'labels', 'children', 'numbers') but the data inside the object will be of equal length. So, for a dynamic object, how I shud be writing the code?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any built in javascript functions, but you can create a for loop (assuming that all arrays in the object are of same length):

```
for(let i = 0; i < initial[Object.keys(initial)[0]].length; i++){
    FINAL_OUTPUT.push({
        labels: initial.labels[i],
        children: initial.children[i],
        numbers: initial.numbers[i]
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let initial = {
    labels: ['label1', 'label2', 'label3'],
  children: ['child1', 'child2', 'child3'],
  numbers: [1 , 2 , 3]
};

let keys = Object.keys(initial);
let keyLength = keys[0].length;
let sampleValueArray = initial[keys[0]];
let i = 0;

let result = sampleValueArray.map( (item,index) => {
  let temp = {};
    keys.forEach( key => 
      temp[key] = initial[key][index]
    )
  return temp
})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let initial = {
  labels: ['label1', 'label2', 'label3'],
  children: ['child1', 'child2', 'child3'],
  numbers: [1, 2, 3]
}

/* FINAL_OUTPUT = [
    { labels: 'label1', children: 'child1', numbers: 1 },
    { labels: 'label2', children: 'child2', numbers: 2 },
        { labels: 'label3', children: 'child3', numbers: 3 }
]; */

const result = Object.keys(initial).reduce((acc, x, i, keys) => {
  const arr = keys.map((y, j) => initial[y][i]);
  acc = [...acc, keys.reduce((acc_2, z, k) => ({
    ...acc_2,
    [z]: arr[k]
  }), [])]
  return acc
}, [])

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let FINAL_OUTPUT =[]

for(let i =0;i<initial.length;i++){
 FINAL_OUTPUT.push(
 {labels: initial.labels[i],
 children: initial.children[i],
 numbers: initial.numbers[i]
 })
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, including an explanation of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to ADD EXPLANATION and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. Remember to format code properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use lodash's `_.flow()` to create a function that:

1. Uses to pairs to get an array of array of [key, [values]] pairs
2. Unzip to get separate keys from values
3. Destructure the keys and the values. Use `_.unzip()` to transpose the values, and then map, and use `_.zipObject()` with the keys to create the objects.

```js
const { flow, toPairs, unzip, zipObject } = _;

const fn = flow(
  toPairs, // convert to [key, values] pair
  unzip, // transpose to array of keys, and array of values
  ([keys, values]) => // destructure keys and values
    unzip(values) // transpose the values
      .map(vals => zipObject(keys, vals)) // create object from keys and each set of values
);

const initial = {
  labels: ['label1', 'label2', 'label3'],
  children: ['child1', 'child2', 'child3'],
  numbers: [1, 2, 3]
};

const result = fn(initial);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
```